# Trying to construct a subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

> Let $(x_n)$ be a real valued sequence. I want to construct a subsequence $(y_n) $ of $(x_n) $ such that no two consecutive terms of the sequence $(
> y_n) $ are same and also if $(y_n) $ is Cauchy then $(x_n) $ is also Cauchy.

Intuitively it is very clear that whenever there are two consecutive equal terms in $(x_n) $ say $x_m=x_{m+1}$, then I won't consider $x_{m+1}$ in $(y_n) $. How should i write this sequence $(y_n) $ mathematically?

Comment: You cannot do this if $(x_n)$ is a constant sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been pointed out, that isn't always possible. The case where it isn't possible is when $(x_n)$ is an eventually constant sequence. A sequence $(a_n)$ is eventually constant if there exists an integer $N$ and a value $c$ such that $\forall n \ge N: a_n =c$.

It's obvious that you can't find an (infinite) subsequence $(y_n)$ that isn't also eventually constant, contradicting your condition $\forall n:y_{n+1} \ne y_n$.

If $(x_n)$ isn't eventually constant, then one possible index sequence $n_k$ for the subsequence $(y_k) = (x_{n_k})$ can be defined inductively step by step as:

$$n_1=1, \forall k\ge 1: n_{k+1}=\min \{i\; |\; i>n_k, x_i \neq x_{n_k}\}$$

$(x_n)$ not being eventually constant makes the definition of $n_{k+1}$ (the smallest index following $n_k$ where the $(x_n)$ sequence takes a different value than $x_{n_k}$) valid, there always exists such an index.

Comment: What do you mean by arg in the definition?

Comment: @MathLover That was incorrect notation, sorry. I now changed it to a minimum over a certain set, as described in the parenthical after the formula.

Comment: Makes sense now, thanks.